# PyGTK blocking non-GUI threads

Tags: python, multithreading, pygtk

I want to play with the thread-bugs with PyGTK. I have this code so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import pygtk
pygtk.require('2.0')
import gtk
import threading
from time import sleep

class SomeNonGUIThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, tid):
        super(SomeNonGUIThread, self).__init__()
        self.tid = tid

    def run(self):
        while True:
            print "Client #%d" % self.tid
            sleep(0.5)

class App(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        super(App, self).__init__()

        self.window = gtk.Window()
        self.window.set_size_request(300, 300)
        self.window.set_position(gtk.WIN_POS_CENTER)
        self.window.connect('destroy', gtk.main_quit)

        self.window.show_all()

    def run(self):
        print "Main start"
        gtk.main()
        print "Main end"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()

    threads = []
    for i in range(5):
        t = SomeNonGUIThread(i)
        threads.append(t)

    # Ready, set, go!
    for t in threads:
        t.start()

    # Threads work so well so far
    sleep(3)

    # And now, they freeze :-(
    app.start()
```

It does that NonGUIThreads are running for 3 seconds concurently. Afterwards, the window is shown and other threads are **stoped**! After closing the window, threads are running again.

How it is possible, that `gtk.main()` is able to block other threads? The threads do not depend on any lock, so they should work during the window is shown.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to call `gobject.threads_init()` before you do anything Gtk related.

[More info in PyGtk's FAQ](http://faq.pygtk.org/index.py?file=faq20.006.htp&req=show)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I found that page but I thought it is just for situation when threads want to communicate with GTK. I was wrong.